# How to capture a specific area on the sketch in Processing

Tags: screenshot, processing, processing.js

I want to take a screenshot of a specific area in the sketch (in processing). 
With `save();` and `saveFrame();` references I can't do it because they capture the whole area, but i just need a smaller specific are to capture. How to do it properly?

Comment: processing-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Processing reference.  There's a function called `get` that may be called on PImages or the drawing screen itself.  You don't mention whether you want to capture some weird shape or a rectangle, so I'll assume a standard rectangle.  According to its [documentation](http://processing.org/reference/get_.html), what you want is:

**Syntax**: get(x, y, w, h)

**Parameters**:

- x    int: x-coordinate of the pixel
- y    int: y-coordinate of the pixel
- w    int: width of pixel rectangle to get
- h    int: height of pixel rectangle to get

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem! Thanks a lot! I am very new to processing so I haven't heard of `get` before:)

Answer (score 1):

As kevinsa5 said `get(x, y, w, h)` is the way to go, and to save it, you may use a PImage to hold the capture, like:

```
int sliceW = 50;
int sliceH = 50;
int number = 1 ;

PImage slice;

void setup(){
  size (300, 300);
  slice = createImage(sliceW, sliceH, ARGB);
  noFill();
}

void draw(){
  stroke(random(10,90),random(100,200),random(80,120));
  line(0, frameCount%height, width, frameCount%height );
}

void mouseClicked(){
captureAndSave(mouseX, mouseY, sliceW, sliceH);
}

void captureAndSave(int x, int y, int w, int h){
  slice = get(x, y, w, h);
  slice.save("slice" + nf(number, 4) + ".png");
  number++;
  println("saved!");
}
```